# PHP foreach loop for all images in a HTML 3 table column

Tags: php

Hi I'm a newbie with PHP and this site, so please be nice :)

I'm currently having trouble working the below PHP foreach code out as I'm trying to echo all images in a HTML table 3 column but it echo's with 2 only.

**UPDATE: I've managed to fix some issues thanks to the comments guy's, thank you. However, I', now experiencing another issue which is confusing.**

Basically, If I have one picture in a folder, it will echo that one picture, but If I put two pictures there, it echo's out with 4, 1 first picture echo's with 2 and the second is with 2 as well. Basically showing 4 images even though I have 2 images in that folder. I can't seem to fix this..

Here's the code:

```
<?php
// get images
$images = glob($imagedir.'/' . "*.png");
$i = 0;
echo'<table><tr>';
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $i++;
   echo '<td><img src="'.$image.'" height="200"></td>';
   if($i == 3)
   {
       echo '</tr><tr>';
       $i = 0;
   }
}
echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: don't open and close your PHP while you're doing your foreach loop. Also, foreach loops don't end with `endforeach`, you end them with a curly bracket `}`.  Example of a foreach `<?php foreach($images as $image){ echo "$image<br>"; } ?>`

Comment: He is using alternative syntax for the same, its valid

Comment: Ok, that's new to me, never seen that before. My bad.

Comment: Did you check your array, print_r($images); is it really content 3 values?

Comment: heey I think your updated issue has to do maybe with you resetting the $i variable to 0 in the if statement.

Comment: I can't fix the problem, it shows duplicate pictures of 1 another.

Comment: Off topic: your glob function also returns directories which are names end with .png. To prevent possible future errors, make sure you never have such directories, or make sure you've only grabbed file names

Answer (score 0):

You're code for rendering the HTML is just fine.
If you have duplicates, the content of your imagedir must be wrong.

A few remarks:

1. `glob($imagedir.'/' . "*.png");` also include directories which names end as `.png`.
2. Depending on the amount of images, the last table row will not be completely filled with table cells.
3. It's good practice not using the php closing tag `?>` at the end a the php file.

I've altered you code to avoid above to problems.
I'm sure there more/other ways to do this, but this came in mind first.

```
<?php
    $imagedir = 'images';
    //Get *.png files only
    $images = array_filter(glob("$imagedir/*.png"), 'is_file');

    //Make image array divisble by 3 (columns)
    while (count($images) % 3 != 0) {
        $images[] = '';
    }

    echo'<table><tr>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($images); $i++) {
        //Render TD if $image is not empty
        if ($images[$i-1] != '' != '') {
            echo '<td><img src="' . $images[$i-1] . '">', "<br>Image $i</td>";
        }
        //Close table row after 3 TD's
        if($i % 3 == 0) 
        {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr></table>';
```